# Nonewline python

Tags: python, output

I am trying to print random numbers using random , but when I try to print the output in one line using `end= " "` the output doesnt show anything until I break the program.

```
import random
import time
while True:
    x = random.randint(1,6)
    print(x, end=" ")
    time.sleep(1)
```

The out put is like this after I interrupt :

```
C1 2 3 5 5 4 5 4 1 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable buffering by passing `flush=True` to `print` function (in python3)

```
print(x, end=" ", flush=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing it as follows:

```
print('Hello World!', flush=True , end = " ")
```

Comment: This solution doesn't differ from the one posted a few minutes ago.